# Do all users need access to the postgres database in pg_hba.conf?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, pgadmin

I was just testing the user creation process in pgAdmin. I have a database `db1` for which I want to create a user to be able to connect to it. I want this to be the only database the user can connect to.

After creating the user, I opened my `pg_hba.conf` file and added a couple of lines:

```
host    db1 dbuser  127.0.0.1/32    md5
host    db1 dbuser  ::1/128         md5
```

The postgres user has access to all the databases:

```
host    all postgres    127.0.0.1/32    md5
host    all postgres    ::1/128         md5
```

When I connect to the server through pgAdmin, I get an error indicating that `dbuser` doesn't have access to the `postgres` database.

Is this normal? Should dbuser even require access to the postgres database, when I want him to only access `db1`? As soon as I add postgres to the list of databases for `dbuser`, I can connect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see is **pgAdmin** connecting to the configured  **Maintenance DB** - which is `postgres` by default. Select a server in the object browser pane and choose "Properties" from the context menu (right-click). The drop-down menu only offers the typical choices, but you can **just type in any database name**.

If a user's access is limited to *one* database in `pg_hba.conf` (which *is* the most efficient place to do that), you can make it work with pgAdmin by configuring *this one* database as maintenance db. Nothing bad will come of it.

The other option is to grant access to the maintenance DB (`postgres` or whatever) in `pg_hba.conf` additionally.

You can also open all gates in `pg_hba.conf` and regulate access with database permissions, like @a_horse explained in his answer. This is easier to manage, but restricting access in `pg_hba.conf` is safer and faster - more robust against DoS attacks and heavy load. Won't make a big difference in most cases, though.

Quoting the [documentation of pgAdmin 1.22](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin3/1.22/connect.html) (final release of pgAdmin III):

> The maintenance DB field is used to specify the initial database that
>   pgAdmin connects to, and that will be expected to have the [pgAgent](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin3/1.22/pgagent.html#pgagent)
>   schema and [adminpack](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin3/1.22/extend.html#extend) objects installed (both optional). On PostgreSQL
>   8.1 and above, the maintenance DB is normally called 'postgres',
>   and on earlier versions 'template1' is often used, though it is
>   preferable to create a 'postgres' database for this purpose to avoid
>   cluttering the template database.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. To me it makes a whole lot more sense to set up the user config in the pg_hba.conf file since its like a "first line of defense". The fact that the maitenance DB field comes prefilled is misleading.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do this through the pg_hba.conf.

Simply revoke the connect privilege on the database from that user.

However by default public is granted the connect privilege. So you need to first revoke that:

```
revoke connect on db1 from public;
grant connect on db1 to dbuser;
```

You need to run the `revoke ... from public` statement for all databases to make sure only the specific users can connect.

Once you have done that, you can leave pg_hba.conf "open" for all users and all databases.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen the revoke / grant need in some documentation, but I couldn't wrap my head around the need to add postres in the database list for the user to be able connect.