# What is the special database "postgres" for?

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL server with several databases running on it. One of the databases is called `postgres`, and it was there right from the beginning. I could not see any tables inside and I've never used it explicitly, but I noticed, that any user is allowed to create tables within the database (this is not what I want - I do not want any users except the administrator to create any tables anywhere).

I have a feeling that it is some kind of a special database that is required for a normal operation of the server, but **what is exactly its purpose?** What kind of data is (or could be) stored inside? Does it hold the metadata about other databases (e.g. the `information_schema`?). Can something nasty happen, if I revoke `connect` privilege to this database from public? Or if I even drop it?

I googled for half an hour, but always got completely unrelated stuff, because the word `postgres` is also used for the user `postgres` and the DBMS itself.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is nothing special about it. As described in PostgreSQL documentation, [Creating a Database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-createdb.html), you need to be connected to a database, in order to create another one:

> Since you need to be connected to the database server in order to execute the `CREATE DATABASE` command, the question remains how the first database at any given site can be created. The first database is always created by the `initdb` command when the data storage area is initialized. (See Section 17.2.) This database is called `postgres`. **So to create the first "ordinary" database you can connect to `postgres`.**

and in [Template Databases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html):

> **Note:** `template1` and `template0` do not have any special status beyond the fact that the name `template1` is the default source database name for `CREATE DATABASE`. For example, one could drop `template1` and recreate it from `template0` without any ill effects. This course of action might be advisable if one has carelessly added a bunch of junk in `template1`. (To delete `template1`, it must have `pg_database.datistemplate = false`.)
>
> **The `postgres` database** is also created when a database cluster is initialized. **This database is meant as a default database for users and applications to connect to.** It is simply a copy of `template1` and **can be dropped and recreated if necessary.**

Comment: Yep. In practice you should generally leave it empty and unchanged as a handy place to connect to. This is really a wart in PostgreSQL, a consequence of the fact that PostgreSQL doesn't let you connect to "no database in particular" like other DBMSes do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a good answer! I denied access of public users to `postgres` and everything still works, except one thing: pgAdmin III does not connect anymore unless I specify the targed database in the `Maintenance DB` field. It seems that it used to connect to `postgres` database before.

Comment: @RKiselev Yeah, it works like that. Just like **ypercube** wrote, it's default database to connect to.

Comment: Pgadmin has "maintenance database" property. Just change it to your db that you want to connect

Comment: @RKiselev: About pgAdmin and its "maintenance database": [What is the Maintenance DB asked by pgAdmin?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68087/3684)